# Powering 7970 HD cards. Separated cables or single cables?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, amd-radeon, pci-express

I just received my new computer.

It has multiple GPUs (XFX 7970 HD). They have two power sockets:

- a 8 pin socket and
- a 6 pin socket.

Can I power each card with a single power line? My PSU (Corsair RM1000) comes with PCIe cables that feature two 6+2 pin connectors.

Or do I need to use a separate line on each socket?

Comment: Are you asking if you need both an 8 pin and a 6 pin cable to power it? If so, yes, you do need both. .-.

Comment: Sorry @DanteThegregore, I might not have been too clear haha! What I'm asking is if I need *separated* lines coming from the PSU to the card for each of the plugs on the GPU, or if I can use the same cable for both plugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single power line is enough, there is no reason to use multiple cables for a single video card.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why they would put 2 different plug on the card in that case..

Comment: that I can't answer, I don't know enough about physical structure of video cards to know why manufacturers put 2 different slots. It could be related to different components that need to be powered on modern video card.

Comment: Apparently you are right, this popped on a old reddit thread:
http://i.imgur.com/rYhlBZM.png

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine. You can split the power connector to the layout that you need.

A lot of power supplies have ratings for each connector type (12v rail, 5v rail, 3.3v rail) for the maximum amps that they can push. I never concerned myself with this until I started to mine Bitcoins and had several USB Dongles daisy chained on a back plate board. The board required a 5v rail with a 30 amp load.

Here is a pic for your PSU ([source](http://www.corsair.com/us/media/cms/manual/corsair-psu-spec-table-091813.pdf)). If you're splitting off of the 12v rail, you should be fine (which in great likely hood you would be). However, I would be cautious because having a large load on thin wires could catch fire.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm mining scrypt coins  with this rig. Do you reckon that 83.3A on the 12V rail and 25A on the 3.3V is enough for 3 of these XDX 7970 HD?